# putting NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults into a tableview via NSDictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I've pieced together a few snippets from around stackoverflow, but I can't seem to get this behaving as I'd expect.

I am trying to take the NSUSerDefaults and populate a UITableView with the data.

The dictionary is populated, and all the NSLog's output what I expect. But the final `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not returning anything to the table view.

I have the cell identifier and reuse set to "cell" but the table view is coming up empty

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    myDictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation]; }
    NSLog(@"Dict: %@",myDictionary);
    NSLog(@"count: %d", [myDictionary count]);
    NSArray * allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    NSLog(@"%@",allKeys);

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1; }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [myDictionary count]; }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSArray * allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    cell.textLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];;

    return cell; }
```

at the head of my `myTableViewController.m` file I have:

```
@interface myTableViewController ()
{
    NSDictionary *myDictionary;
}
```

Comment: Is `myDictionary` a strong variable?

Comment: **Note**: Using an `NSDictionary` as the basis for a table view doesn't work. A dictionary has no order. In `viewDidLoad` you should load the keys into an array and keep that in an instance variable. This array should be used as the basis for all of the data source and delegate methods.

Comment: @H2CO3 it's at the top of my .m file, see edit

Comment: @rmaddy I am using an array, the last four lines of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath use the keys in an array to interact with the dictionary

Comment: @Madivad Thanks, strange, by default ivars should be strong...

Comment: @Madivad But in theory, the call to `[myDictionary allKeys]` could give an array in a different order or a different size as time goes on. You need to call that once and hold onto it. Otherwise your data model could change behind your back.

Comment: I'm thinking it's more to do with populating the tableview, but I just can't see where I've got it wrong. As I said, I have the cell identifier set, style is "right detail" (I've tried the others)... I'm not using a tableviewcontroller, it's a tableview object in a viewcontroller. Is that it?

Comment: Did you make your view controller the table view's `dataSource` and `delegate`?

Comment: I added the protocols to the .h, but I forgot the actual connections... Thanks @rmaddy  But now I'm getting this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a23ec0'`

Comment: You appear to have hooked your delegate to your view, not your view controller

Comment: @Madivad Why did you add the protocols to the .h file? You should add them to the class extension in the .m file.

Comment: sorry @rmaddy not protocols, I meant the `<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` at the end of the interface line in the .h. If you add an answer I can give you the tick. And @CodaFi too, at least give you a +1. Thanks guys

Comment: @Madivad Those are protocols. There is no need to add that to the .h. Add it to the class extension in the .m.

Comment: @Madivad I posted an answer summarizing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from the comments.

Update your .m as follows (typed quickly - possible typos below):

```
@interface myTableViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *myDictionary;
    NSArray *myKeys;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    myDictionary = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation]; 
    myKeys = [defaults allKeys];

    // not sure where your table view is created but set the dataSource and delegate
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return myKeys.count; 
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){ 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *key = myKeys[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = myDictionary[key];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = myDictionary[key];

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming your uitableviewcell is not nil after dequeueing

this should solve your issue if your dictionary is not a problem:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){ 
       cell = *create your tableviewcell here*;
    }
    NSArray * allKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    cell.textLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [myDictionary objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];;

    return cell; }
```

Comment: This is true but he hasn't even gotten this far yet :)